# Why do I get an "invalid pointer" when freeing a pointer to a struct in C

Tags: c, pointers, struct, free

I have just been trying to relearn structs in C, so I made this test code. In it, I have been able to successfully create a pointer to a struct in C. The code works just fine without the two free statements at the end.

However, when I add the free statements at the end of the code, I get an error of having an invalid pointer. I thought I correctly allocated the memory for the pointer to a struct as well as freeing it. I also only deallocated everything that was a pointer.

I will get an output: (last 2 lines are added only when the free statements are included in the code)

```
5
5 10 0x7ffc7ee52e04 20
55 40 0x7ffc7ee52e08 2000
free(): invalid pointer
Aborted (core dumped)
```

How do I fix this and why?
(This is my first stack overflow post ever, so sorry if there is anything I did wrong or if anything is not clear)

Thank you!

Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


int main() {
        struct point_struct {
                int length;
                int width;
                int *height;
        };

        struct point_struct house;  // Ignore house struct, everything here worked fine.

        house.length = 5;
        printf("%i\n", house.length);    
        house.width = 10;
        int var = 20;
        house.height = &var;
        printf("%i %i %p %i\n", house.length, house.width, house.height, *house.height);



        struct point_struct *plane = NULL;  // Declare plane pointer to struct

        plane = malloc(sizeof(struct point_struct));   // Allocate memory for pointer to plane struct
        if (plane == NULL) {
                printf("MEMORY ALLOCATION FAILED plane\n");
                exit(1);
        }


        int pLength = 55;  // Values to be stored in plane
        int pWidth = 40;
        int pHeight = 2000;

        (*plane).length = 55;   // Both (*). and -> dereference AND
        plane->width = 40;      // get an element of a struct
        int pValue = 2000;      

        (*plane).height = malloc(sizeof(int));    // Allocates memory for height in pointer to plane struct
        if ((*plane).height == NULL) {
                free(plane);
                printf("ALLOCATE MEMORY FAILURE, plane->length\n");
                exit(1);
        }
        plane->height = &pHeight;

        // prints values inside of plane including an address
        printf("%i %i %p %i\n", plane->length, plane->width, plane->height, *(plane->height));

        free(plane->height);  // Adding these 2 lines is supposed to free the struct.
        free(plane);          // However, they cause the error
 

        return 0;
}
```

Comment: Change: `plane->height = &pHeight;` into `*plane->height = pHeight;`

Comment: `plane->height` backtracking: `plane->height = &pHeight;` `int pHeight = 2000;` Not dynamically allocated - it is wrong to attempt to free it. However, there was also a `(*plane).height = malloc(sizeof(int));` that was never freed, this is a leak and needed to be freed while you still had the address. You don't free because it's a pointer; you free because it was malloc'ed (calloc'ed/ realloc'ed) and hasn't already been freed.

Comment: But why have `height` in the struct be a pointer? Especially when the other two fields are `int`?

Comment: I wasn't creating anything with the struct, I was just testing my understanding on structs/pointers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
int pHeight = 2000; 

(*plane).height = malloc(sizeof(int)); 
if ((*plane).height == NULL) { 
    free(plane);
    printf("ALLOCATE MEMORY FAILURE, plane->length\n");
    exit(1);
}

plane->height = &pHeight;

free(plane->height)
```

1. You allocate memory for a `int` and make `height` point to this memory.
2. You then you make `height` point to `pHeight` which is a variable with automatic storage duration. This as a result leads to a memory leak since the memory you `malloc()`'d is now lost.
3. You then call `free()` on `height`, which is pointing to memory that isn't from `malloc()`, `calloc()` or `realloc()`, so using `free()` on it is invalid.

The `free()` man page says:

```
void free(void *ptr);
```

```
The free() function frees the memory
space pointed to by ptr, which must
have been returned by a previous call
to malloc(), calloc() or realloc().
```

Answer (score 0):

When you call `free(plane->height)`, it's pointing at the local variable `pHeight`.  You're only permitted to call `free` with a pointer that was `return`ed via something in the `malloc` family.

Answer (score 0):

You allocated dynamically memory for an object of the type `int`

```
(*plane).height = malloc(sizeof(int));    // Allocates memory for height in pointer to plane struct
```

But then you reassigned the value of the pointer

```
plane->height = &pHeight;
```

that now points to the local variable `pHeight`

```
int pHeight = 2000;
```

So the code produces a memory leak because the address of the dynamically allocated memory is lost. And you may not call the function `free` for a pointer that points to a local variable.

Instead you should write

```
*plane->height = pHeight;
```